# Error during installation from try ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, root

I'm currently using Windows 8 64-bit OS and I want to use ubuntu alongside it. But while I try to install, I'm always stuck on an error message `No root file system defined`

I've even tried to use gpart but I've no idea what to do there. I'm completely new to ubuntu and linux.

I don't want to lose windows or any of my data.

I've a 20 GB partition which I've thought of using to install ubuntu. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `something else` option while installing?

Answer (score 0):

You should go thru the below properly before starting the installation of Ubuntu...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiOSBoot
http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony